# Can't upgrade to Magento enterprise 2.4.2-p1

Tags: upgrade, magento-upgrade, magento-enterprise-2

Currently we have Magento 2.4.2 Enterprise version .magento 2.4.2-p1 is released on may 11. But we can not upgrade to 2.4.2-p1 version .
while run composer update command,below ,error thrown

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2::onPrePoolCreate
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.2-p1, found magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.2] but it does not match the constraint.``
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are having composer version 2 installed then try downgrading to the Composer version 1 like

```
composer self-update 1.10.12
```

Hope this will solve the issue.